# How to find kernel debuginfos href (web access)

Tags: 14.04, crash

I got a kernel crashdump KDUMP format with signature

```
3.13.0-46-generic
#77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015
x86_64
```

I need to wget the .ddebs for it, looking at 
    http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/
I can't find it.
I guess there are other place to look at ?